# Knot Groups in S^3 vs 3-space

Tags: knot-theory

I am reading Knots by Burde and Zieschang (2nd edition). In it the authors claim that for a knot $K$ there exists an isomorphism $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus K)\cong \pi_1(S^3\setminus K)$ that is induced by inclusion.

This should be straightforward however consider the case of the unknot $S^1$. $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus S^1$ deformation retracts to a torus, and if we view $S^1$ in $S^3$ as line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ then we obtain a deformation retraction of $S^3\setminus S^1$ onto $S^1$. Clearly the fundamental groups of the torus and the circle are not the same.

Am I doing something stupid?

Comment: You can't view $S^1$ as a line in $\Bbb R^3$ for this, that's not an embedding.

Comment: @runway44 It's reasonably common in knot theory to implicitly use stereographic projections. In this case it's projecting from a point along the knot.

Comment: @KyleMiller Yes, that was obvious to me. I was saying this doesn't apply here as it makes the isomorphism of $\pi_1$s untrue.

Comment: @runway44 It works fine here since stereographic projection is a homeomorphism on the complements. But I'd believe the authors only proved the stated isomorphism when $K$ is actually homeomorphic to a circle in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus S^1$ doesn't deformation retract onto the torus, but rather a torus with a disk.  This is homotopy equivalent to the wedge sum $S^2\vee S^1$, which has the correct fundamental group.

This shows, though, that homotopically there's a difference up in $\pi_2$. That's from the fact that $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus S^1$ is homeomorphic to $S^3$ minus a circle and a point, but $\mathbb{R}^3$ minus a line is homeomorphic to $S^3$ minus a circle. Removing that extra point makes $\pi_2$ be nontrivial.

Comment: Thank you it is clear now!